# TLS handshake failed with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, client-applications

trying to connecting to the blockchain hyperledger network using node Js app.

Doing invoke() to the chaincode using client app showing this error.

Can anyone please help me out for this issue